# CSS selector for next and previous elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I target the list element individually, for example I would like to make:

Html:

```
<ul class="roundabout-holder">
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item roundabout-in-focus"></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
    <li class="roundabout-moveable-item"></li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
.roundabout-in-focus{
font-size:1em;
}

.roundabout-in-focus.prev(),
.roundabout-in-focus.next(){
font-size:.9em;
} 


.roundabout-in-focus.prev().prev(),
.roundabout-in-focus.next().next(){
font-size:.8em;
}

.roundabout-in-focus.prev().prev().prev(),
.roundabout-in-focus.next().next().next(){
font-size:.7em;
}
```

That means the further away the .roundabout-in-focus, the smaller the list element's font size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every next sibling can be represented with a `+ .roundabout-moveable-item`, however [there is no equivalent for previous siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector).

As you need to style the next and previous elements *relative* to the element being designated as `.roundabout-in-focus`, you will not be able to do this using other techniques such as `:not(.roundabout-in-focus)`. Therefore you can't do this using pure CSS.

If you're using jQuery, which I'm assuming based on the `.prev()` and `.next()` notations in your example, this should be relatively easy to accomplish.